# LinearLayout height change with adding new view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some nested Layouts in my GUI.
Don't ask me why I made it like that or why don't I use grid layout...my question is something else.

My layout looks like [THIS](http://d.pr/i/MqGN)

After I add any view, let's say a button, to any of these 4 relative layouts, it changes to [THIS](http://d.pr/i/XqCG)

I set the Relative layout's weight to 0dp. That way, width is not changed when I add another view to a Layout. But I don't know what to do about the height. If i set it to 0dp as well, it ofc, disappears.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/rising_sun_blue"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#333111"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#123132"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, My question is, is there any piece of code that will "glue" my layouts and make them stay exactly like on the first screenshot, after I add bunch of new views in it !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the both nested LinearLayouts android:layout_height="match_parent" and not wrap_content.